# is there any ways to tidy up or parse messy data in excel

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, jupyter

I am trying to parse data from excel into a new table to tidy up the data.

I have already tried to parse them manually but there is too many data

This is the original data from excel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4xgU.jpg

I am trying to get this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifqe2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Since exec seems to be the constant, I would iterate through the excel and create a dictionary with the exec as the key and another dictionary as a value. Inside that dictionary I would define each category.

ex.

```py
dictionary = {John Smith:{Bus:123,Fax:sdfas,Res:adsf}, Adam Smith:{Bus:123,Fax:sdfas,Res:adsf}}
```

Then you simply write something to take data from the dictionary and put it in excel in your chosen format.

Comment: I have 8000 lines of data to retrieve so i don't think I will be able to iterate through the excel file?

Comment: If all of your data follows the same format as the stuff you posted this can easily be done. If there is a pattern to the data you can iterate easily. What excel library are you using?

Comment: not sure what library, this is simply a simple excel file

Comment: You need a library to open and save the excel files. Read the docs on openpyxl and that should get you going.

Comment: Does all of your data follow this same pattern? If so i can help you get started

Comment: yes, i think so. but some have certain data some don't have certain data.

Comment: but the header for the new table should just be the same

Comment: Thats not a problem. Start off by reading this: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/ that will get you going in the right direction. As problems arise just google them or post here and you will find your answers. Your looking at a good chunk of code here. And you havent really given much for me to help you with besides your end goal, and it wouldnt really be fair if i just wrote this for you.